# how to run multiple firebase promises and then once completed, execute function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I need to execute `2 firebase calls` to retrieve specific data from the database. `Once these promises resolve`, I want to call another function with the data retrieved. How can I do this? ..something with `Promise.All?`

Code below:

```
app.post('/testtwilio', function(req, res) {
  //save request variables
  var to_UID = req.body.to;
  var from_UID = req.body.from;
  var experience_id = req.body.exp_id;

  //Query firebase and save 'zone_id' which we need later
  firebase.database().ref('experiences').child(experience_id).once('value').then((snap) => {
    zone_id = snap.val().ZoneID;
  });

  //Query firebase and save 'from_name' which we need later
  firebase.database().ref('users').child(from_UID).once('value').then((snap) => {
    from_name = snap.val().Name;
  });

  //Once we have the two variables returned and saved
  //Call a final firebase query and a twilio function with all the recieved data
  firebase.database().ref('users').child(to_UID).once('value').then((snap) => {
    //Do something with this aggregated data now
    client.messages.create({
      //blah blah do something with the saved data that we retrieved
      var phone = snap.val().Phone;
      var msg = from_name + zone_id + from_UID + experience_id
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Promise.all` since `once('value')` returns one.

Quick n dirty example:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(firebase.database().ref('experiences').child(experience_id).once('value'));
promises.push(firebase.database().ref('users').child(from_UID).once('value'));

// Wait for all promises to resolve
Promise.all(promises).then(function(res) {        
    // res[0] is your experience_id snapshot
    // res[1] is your from_UID snapshot
    // Do something...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NodeJS of version 7.6 and higher you can also write this code with async function, which much simpler to read and maintain

```
// ...

const wrap = require('express-async-wrap')

// ...
                        // need to wrap async function 
                        // to make it compatible with express
app.post('/testtwilio', wrap(async (req, res) => {
  const to_UID = req.body.to
  const from_UID = req.body.from
  const experience_id = req.body.exp_id

  const [
    snap1,
    snap2,
    snap3

  // waiting for all 3 promises
  ] = await Promise.all([
    firebase.database().ref('experiences').child(experience_id).once('value'),
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(from_UID).once('value'),
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(to_UID).once('value')
  ])

  const zone_id = snap1.val().ZoneID
  const from_name = snap2.val().Name
  const phone = snap3.val().Phone
  const msg = from_name + zone_id + from_UID + experience_id

  // ...
  client.messages.create(...)
}))
```